# How to delete alias and virtualhost in apache on WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp, alias, virtualhost

Seems like such a simple thing, but I cannot find a nice easy guide to deleting an alias and virtualhost in apache ( WAMP server ), I just made a mistake by setting up dev.mysite as an alias, but forgot I was going to use this for staging on the host, so what I want to do is delete that, and recreate it as local.mysite for the WAMP localhost. It's easy to create them, but there isn't any easy to find link about how to delete them, and even an internet search didn't give me the answer in the first 3 pages of search results.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing someone will say this is answered in another post, but I searched the whole site using search terms: delete apache wamp alias virtualhost and got no relevant results ... however if it is to be kept, I found the answer: editing the httpd-vhosts.conf file ( remove the entry, save, restart all services ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's probably best if there's a better question to replace it that someone else has already posted (that I just didn't find). I had done this ages ago, but having not touched it for years I'd forgotten, and was surprised when those search terms didn't give me any results. If you think it's worth keeping here rather than just deleting, what kinds of things exactly do you want it to have, because the source I found which gave me the reminder wasn't worth citing, it was just enough to remind me.